# robot_localization with hector_sim_imu in 3D mode, robot starts flying up

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Really a head scratcher here, my /odometry/filtered always end up with a z velocity and my robot just starts floating upwards. I am using a wheel odom and an imu only. If I disable the imu, the wheel odom works ok.

I am using the hector sim imu on an ENU frame_id:

```
<plugin name="imu_controller" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_imu.so">
            <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
            <updateRate>50.0</updateRate>
            <bodyName>imu_link_sim</bodyName>
            <topicName>vectornav/IMU</topicName>
            <accelDrift>0.005 0.005 0.005</accelDrift>
            <accelGaussianNoise>0.005 0.005 0.005</accelGaussianNoise>
            <rateDrift>0.005 0.005 0.005 </rateDrift>
            <rateGaussianNoise>0.005 0.005 0.005 </rateGaussianNoise>
            <headingDrift>0.005</headingDrift>
            <headingGaussianNoise>0.005</headingGaussianNoise>
          </plugin>
```

In RVIZ, I double check that the imu_link_sim axis is as follows:

> RED: East  Green: North Blue: Up

Here is my config:

```
initial_state:  [0.0,  0.0,  0.59,
                 0.0,  0.0,  0,
                 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                 0.0,  0.0,  0.0]

frequency: 60

sensor_timeout: 0.1

two_d_mode: false

transform_time_offset: 0.0

# Use this parameter to provide specify how long the tf listener should wait for a transform to become available. 
# Defaults to 0.0 if unspecified.
transform_timeout: 0.0

# Whether to broadcast the transformation over the /tf topic. Defaults to true if unspecified.
publish_tf: true

# Whether to publish the acceleration state. Defaults to false if unspecified.
publish_acceleration: false



map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified
odom0: wheel_odom
odom0_config: [true, true, false,
              false,  false,  true,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              false, false, false]

odom0_queue_size: 5

odom0_differential: false

odom0_relative: false

#
imu0: vectornav/IMU
#The IMU gives orientation, linear acceleration, and angular velocity
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              false, false, false]

imu0_differential: true
imu0_relative: true
imu0_queue_size: 5

# [ADVANCED] Some IMUs automatically remove acceleration due to gravity, and others don't. If yours doesn't, please set
# this to true, and *make sure* your data conforms to REP-103, specifically, that the data is in ENU frame.
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
```

Am I missing something here? This seems to happen as soon as I start moving the robot, not when it first loads.

EDIT, perhaps its because the IMU is so noisy? Here is the plot of the z acceleration when the robot drives forward.  Note the spikes happen everytime I move, and recedes as soon as I stop. Do I need to filter the z acceleration somehow?
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350534/robot_localization-with-hector_sim_imu-in-3d-mode,-robot-starts-flying-up/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-04-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hashirzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53034/hashirzahir/) on 2020-04-24**:
Does it have to do with the `imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true`? Perhaps you could also include a snippet of the raw data from the imu sensor `rostopic echo /robot/imu/imu/data -n1`.

**Comment by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on 2020-04-24**:
it appears that the linear_acceleration/z reported from the imu sensors starts oscillating between 9.4-10.2 once I start to move, and continue to do this even after stopping. This huge discrepancy is the cause, but I've no idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have `two_d_mode` set to *false*, but aren't measuring `Z` in any way. Every single pose variable should either be measured directly or as a velocity. When you tell the filter that it should estimate the state of a variable, but don't actually provide any measurements for that variable, then the covariance for that variable will explode, and any measurements to correlated variables will cause motion in the unmeasured variable.

Anyway, you need to provide a measurement for Z, and *not* just acceleration. If your robot can't move instantaneously upward, then set the `z` velocity in your `odom0_config` to *true*, so that it fuses the 0 Z velocity values. I'd also do the same for Y, if the robot is nonholonomic. And make sure you give them tiny covariance values in the odometry data as well.

Also, you are fusing absolute yaw from your IMU *and* your wheel odometry. That's not going to work well, because they aren't going to agree with one another over time. Either your wheel encoder or your IMU config needs to set the yaw value to `false` (but the yaw velocity can remain *true*).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2020-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1